# Symfony Collection Form Controller Problem

Tags: php, symfony, collections, symfony-forms

I have an entity Product. I created a form ProductType with fields :

- Name
- Price
- Reference

I wanted to create a collection to allow user to create and submit several products at once.
Therefore I have created a new Form, which has no entity, Product**s**Type.
This form contains one field :

- Products
  Which is a CollectionType class with entry type ProductType.

In my template, I have used a prototype and the Javascript works perfectly to create it.
Although, none of my entries are persisted in the DB when submitted.
I have search for hours to finally have something inspiring but still not working :
[Symfony: Access an unmapped form field from a CollectionType in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701760/symfony-access-an-unmapped-form-field-from-a-collectiontype-in-controller)

Do you see what's my error (in the Controller I guess) ?

**ProductController**

```
//[...]

class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/product", name="product")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $request = new Request();
        $formProduct = $this->createForm('App\Form\ProductsType');
        $product = new Product();
        $formProduct->handleRequest($request);
        if ($formProduct->isSubmitted() && $formProduct->isValid()) {
            foreach ($formProduct->get('products') as $formChild)
            {
                $product->setName($formChild->get('name')->getData()); // That's it!
                $product->setPrice($formChild->get('price')->getData());
                $product->setReference($formChild->get('reference')->getData());
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($product);
                $entityManager->flush();
            }


            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
        }

        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'formProduct' => $formProduct->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**ProductType**

```
//[...]

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')

            ->add('price')

            ->add('reference')

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**ProductsType**

```
//[...]

class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('products', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ProductType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Product template(twig)**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello ProductController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{{ form_start(formProduct) }}
    {# store the prototype on the data-prototype attribute #}
    <ul id="products-fields-list"
        data-prototype="{{ form_widget(formProduct.products.vars.prototype)|e }}"
        data-widget-tags="{{ '<li></li>'|e }}"
        data-widget-counter="{{ formProduct.products|length }}">
        {% for products in formProduct.products %}
            <li>

                {{ form_row(products) }}
            </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    {{ form_end(formProduct) }}
    <button type="button"
            class="add-another-collection-widget"
            data-list-selector="#products-fields-list">Add another email</button>

    <script>
        // add-collection-widget.js
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.add-another-collection-widget').click(function (e) {
                var list = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('data-list-selector'));
                // Try to find the counter of the list or use the length of the list
                var counter = list.data('widget-counter') || list.children().length;

                // grab the prototype template
                var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');
                // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
                // with a number that's unique to your emails
                // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
                newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);
                // Increase the counter
                counter++;
                // And store it, the length cannot be used if deleting widgets is allowed
                list.data('widget-counter', counter);

                // create a new list element and add it to the list
                var newElem = jQuery(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
                newElem.appendTo(list);
            });
        });

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Hope you'll see something I'm missing. Thank you :)

Comment: You say "none of my entries are persisted" but you don't say what actually does happen. Do you get redirected to the `task_success` route or do you get the form again (filled or unfilled)?

Comment: Indeed, I am not redirect to that page. So I guess it means I do not pass the condition if $formProduct is Submitted & $formProduct is Valid. 
I get the form again, unfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your controller method. The primary problem is your use of `$request = new Request();`. That is creating a new `Request` other than the request sent by the client, so in that empty request there is no form data submitted. The request should be injected as a method parameter so the auto-wiring will build the `Request` from the current http request from the client.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms

Upon making that correction, your code should then get exactly one `Product` persisted with the values of the last one in the form, because you only create one new `Product` and set new values on it each time through the loop. See my comments in the code sample below:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/product", name="product")
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        // line below would create empty Request
        // $request = new Request();
        $formProduct = $this->createForm('App\Form\ProductsType');
        // line below would create only ONE Product that would be overwritten in each iteration
        // $product = new Product();
        $formProduct->handleRequest($request);
        if ($formProduct->isSubmitted() && $formProduct->isValid()) {
            // you only need to fetch the entity manager once
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            foreach ($formProduct->get('products') as $formChild)
            {
                // create a new Product foreach $formChild
                $product = new Product();
                $product->setName($formChild->get('name')->getData()); 
                $product->setPrice($formChild->get('price')->getData());
                $product->setReference($formChild->get('reference')->getData());
                // you only need to fetch the entity manager once
                // $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($product);
                $entityManager->flush();
            }


            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
        }

        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'formProduct' => $formProduct->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer with explanation. It works. I'll read the documentation for the forms because I was missing something you explained.  
Thanks again :)